# Length of an arc from 2 given 3D points and a radius of the arc

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate a length of an arc which goes through 2 Points. I have coordinates from These two Points (x,y,z) and I know the radius of the arc. 
It must be super simple, but I just can`t get it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the distance $d$ between the points, then use the usual formula for a [circular arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)).  The fact that they are in $3$-space does not matter-you are working in the plane defined by the center and the two points.  The length is just $r\theta$ where $\theta=2\arcsin (\frac d{2r})$ is the angle of the arc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you`re right, i was bothering too much how to define a plane, but it all doesn`t matter, because the plane is already defined by 3 Points, the third being the circle Center. That is what I was missing.